# More Information about the Question Answering System called LUKE

Tags: natural-language-processing

LUKE is a new state-of-art in question answering system and after googled keywords LUKE Studio Ousia NAIST and RIKEN AIP (I suppose LUKE is a colaboration between several research centers) I couldn't find any information.

LUKE is mentioned in the following pages:

https://paperswithcode.com/sota/question-answering-on-squad11.

https://sheng-z.github.io/ReCoRD-explorer/.

Is there here anyone with insider information able to explain LUKE?

Comment: Have you read those papers?  Have you done a literature search (e.g., found other papers that cite them and that they cite) to find other related papers?  What have you found?  Can you [edit] your question to summarize what you understand from those papers and articulate a specific question about something concrete you don't understand after reading those papers?

Comment: D.W., you are great at stackexchange, have several badges but sometimes you don't understand the question. Sometimes you don't help...

Comment: Indeed, I probably don't understand this question -- think of this as an opportunity to edit the question to improve it so it's easy even for someone like me to understand!

Comment: My *natural language processing* is challenged even assuming *after **I** googled* or *after **googling***.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. This might be the paper

https://www.researchgate.net/project/LUKE-Project

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340461536_Global_Entity_Disambiguation_with_Pretrained_Contextualized_Embeddings_of_Words_and_Entities

Comment: (In the paper with the long title, I found *Luke* once - as a given name, by the looks of it.)